# Convert String to Double in Spring Expression Language

Tags: spring, hashmap, type-conversion, spring-el

I'm quite new to spring expression language. I have a map which contains values as string.

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "object": {
  "object1": {
    "fields": {
      "value1": {
         "value":"3"
      },
      "value2": {
         "value":"2"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

The spring expression that i have looks something like this,

```
((object['object1'].fields['value1'].value * object['object1'].fields['value2'].value) * 0.5)
```

My calculation method looks like this where SampleObject class has the map object

```
public Double calculation(String expression, SampleObject sampleObject){
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expression);
    Double evaluatedValue = (Double)exp.getValue(sampleObject);
    return evaluatedValue;
}
```

Since the value is string, I get an error saying cannot convert String to Double. This can be eliminated if i change the expression like this

```
((new Double(object['object1'].fields['value1'].value) * new Double(object['object1'].fields['value2'].value)) * 0.5)
```

But I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to change the expression or the object. Is there a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can plugin a class that supports operations on those operand types:

```
class StringDoubleOperatorOverloader implements OperatorOverloader {

    @Override
    public boolean overridesOperation(Operation operation, Object leftOperand,
            Object rightOperand) throws EvaluationException {
        return operation==Operation.MULTIPLY && 
               leftOperand instanceof String && 
               rightOperand instanceof String;
    }

    @Override
    public Object operate(Operation operation, Object leftOperand, Object rightOperand)
            throws EvaluationException {
        Double l = Double.valueOf((String)leftOperand);
        Double r = Double.valueOf((String)rightOperand);
        return l*r;
    }

}
```

Then pass a customized `StandardEvaluationContext` to `getValue()`:

```
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expression);

    StandardEvaluationContext sec = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    sec.setOperatorOverloader(new StringDoubleOperatorOverloader());

    Double evaluatedValue = (Double)exp.getValue(sec,new SampleObject());
```

Comment: This will not work when the expression contains more values and more arithmetic operations, the expression will change, but the format cannot be changed. That's the issue I have. Also i'm passing sampleObject like exp.getValue(sampleObject) because that object is the one that contains the values.

Comment: Surely it would work if you expand the types and operations supported in your plugin operator overloader? You can make the overridesOperation and operate method do whatever you like. I was aiming for a solution where you did not have to change the expression or the object containing the data. The main variation from what you did is that I'm using a two arg version of getValue() that lets me pass in a different evaluation context in addition to the object containing the data. My 'new SampleObject()' is just how I built a testcase representing what you were doing, you can pass in sampleObject.

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSON has `value1.value` and `value2.value` as String the Expression throws the Exception.

Either change your JSON to have Decimal values

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "object": {
  "object1": {
    "fields": {
      "value1": {
         "value":3.0
      },
      "value2": {
         "value":2.0
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Or in the Expression method instead of casting do parsing.

```
public Double calculation(String expression, SampleObject sampleObject){
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expression);
    Double evaluatedValue = Double.parseDouble(exp.getValue(sampleObject).toString()); // This line
    return evaluatedValue;
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, i do not want to change the map. Also your second suggestion would not work because the issue is in the expression and not in the evaluated value. So i still get this error message "The operator 'MULTIPLY' is not supported between objects of type 'java.lang.String' and 'java.lang.String'" Also FYI, the second solution can also be achieved like this, Double evaluatedValue = exp.getValue(sampleObject, Double.class);